# How to underline the space of a string with spacing

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In android xml how to underline the string with the spacing? If I using the underscore it will look not nicely because there are some gap between the underscore.

**Example below are the underline that have gaps**

[image]

**Example below are the one that I looking for:**

[image]

Comment: Well, depending on the font type, you might just be able to use underscores, e.g. look here: `Go_______Travel`

Comment: Other than this, just Google for underlined text in Android; there is a ton of stuff out there which covers this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I still fresh on designing part, can gave me some example? The thing I needed is the underline on the spacing, if using underscore it look not nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make drawable for underscore line and set between that views.

Or use like this

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("Go<u>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</u>Travel"));
```

The output is :

Go_______Travel

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp = "Go     Travel"   
temp=temp.replaceAll(" ", "_"); // return Go______Travel
```

Note that it is just the simple logic, you can obviously use many other solutions based on your application/business logic.

Hope it helps.

Comment: There are the gaps between the underscore, is that the font problem?